# save and get spinner item selected

Tags: android

i want to save spinner value and  retrieve the value of selected item
the problem is i have one spinner with integer and two spinner  with long 
and i don;t know how to get the value with long by using this method 
i want to make this method able to set ints and longs in same method and iwant save these val to sp ,and get it

```
private void spinnerVal(int spinnerID, int move, int selection){
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(spinnerID);
ArrayList<Integer> spinnerOption = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i+=move) {
    spinnerOption.add(i);
}
ArrayAdapter<Integer> integerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerOption);
integerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp.setAdapter(integerArrayAdapter);
sp.setSelection(selection);
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

this is my on item selected method

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Editor editor;
    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1 /*2131492981*/:
            myServer.counter1 = Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putInt("counter1", myServer.counter1);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        case R.id.spinner2 /*2131492983*/:
            myServer.counter2 = (long) (Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()) * 1000);
            editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putLong("counter2", myServer.counter2);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        case R.id.spinner3 /*2131492985*/:
            myServer.counter3 = (long) (Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()) * 1000);
            editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putLong("counter3", myServer.counter3);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        default:
            return;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Integer.valueOf()` for parsing `Long` values when `Spinner` items are `Long`. You have to use `Long.parseLong()` or `Long.valueOf()` instead for parsing `Long` items.

Comment: and i convert it to long by  * 1000