# Retrieve spinner value in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i know i can save and get spinner val by this methods
but if i have long instead of int ,how should i do it

```
 int userChoice = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner",usersChoice);
prefEditor.commit();
```

this to get

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner",-1);
if(spinnerValue != -1) {
  // set the selected value of the spinner 
  spinner.setSelection(spinnerValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the same way you can use putLong and getLong

Comment: If the spinner has only int values because you want to set a Long value? you can cast long value to int.

Comment: setselection((int) val)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759962/save-and-get-spinner-item-selected/46760351#46760351

Comment: setselection(val.intValue())

Answer (score 0):

Your use the `Integer.parseInt` function on the `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition` result:

`Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())`